# Config server - refresh loads removed properties from database

Tags: spring-jdbc, spring-cloud-config-server

I am using a composite config server profile to load properties from native and jdbc. My service starts up loading the properties from both native and database table without any issue.
At runtime, I am trying to update the properties in table and using actuator/refresh API to refresh the changes and I am facing issue as below.

The table has something similar to the below records.

1. key-1   xx  service-1   dev latest
2. key-2   yy  service-1   dev latest

Its updated as below, only the key column is changed.

1. service-1-key-1 yy  service-1   dev latest
2. service-1-key-2 yy  service-1   dev latest

When we refresh, I am getting all the 4 rows loaded into the Properties object, rather I am expecting only the 2 updated records.
Could anyone pls let me know if changing the key is doable and how to do this ?